# How to dynamically refer to TypeScript interface property's value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider this silly example:

```js
interface Building {
  rooms: number
  kitchen: {
    hasOven: true
  }
  bathroom: {
    numberOfSinks: number
  }
}

interface Select<T> {
  name: keyof T
  fields: (keyof T[this.name])[] // <-- This is not valid code. What should I do instead?
}

const x: Select<Building> = {
  name: 'kitchen',
  fields: ['hasOven'] // Because I specified 'kitchen', it only allows 'hasOven'
}

const y: Select<Building> = {
  name: 'bathroom',
  fields: ['numberOfSinks'] // Because I specified 'bathroom', it only allows 'numberOfSinks'
}
```

The above code does not work.

How do I make the `Select<T>` interface to be able to refer to the `name` property's value dynamically and use that to determine the available key values?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done without introducing a second generic type:

```js
interface Select<T, K extends keyof T> {
    name: K
    fields: (keyof T[K])[]
}
```

so now

```js
const a: Select<Building, "bathroom"> = {
    name: 'bathroom',
    fields: ['hasOven'] // NO!
}

const b: Select<Building, "steering-wheel"> = { // NO!
    name: 'steering-wheel',
    fields: ['hasOven'] // NO!
}

const c: Select<Building, "bathroom"> = {
    name: 'steering-wheel', // NO!
    fields: ['numberOfSinks']
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFdgBsAmoDmyA3gFDLnJQD2VAtgM4BcyI6tARtGRQNbBgIAFhBDNSFCckFx6AeQBuI5mCjoI3cgF8NydnDCDqdMTomsO0WTADKoHkxZtOUHdu0lQkWIhTWIWCAQwAB4AFQAaZABpZAgAD0gQHHpkHggATyoYZFCAPmIdEDhaCGYonRhgf2TmAAo0zOzQgG0ogF0ASma2kncEKhB6MGQ45j8AoOCMbDwQfEiAIj4BYRAF-IBeArNi0uQAcmWhEX3wiqrcB2b96TlFEH2evoGh5HSx-0CQ6dwCRb0DEZaOtkFtxBQiiVmPsAYYaLRTudqld9uZnFZbCB7I9eiQSP1BsM4B8Jt9ML85v99HC6CCwYVdtDYUDERJKsjmNdbgoTm1kAB6fnIABysgAhLj8S9huwSV8puTZvNkAshhBoAQALQAd2E-jpxAFQtFEp2UIOao1cx1eqwrIo7MunJuMh5Dz5gpF4slBNeCDlkx+SqpgPhBvB5Ehe32lqgWt16rtkU9JqRTuQ1zRlhsdnoOM0QA)